# Can dynamic array functions be used as a source in a list validation ("dropdown") in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I would like to use the new dynamic array functions in Excel (like `FILTER`, `UNIQUE`, `SORT`) as a source for list validations.

In the following example, all values in column `A` where the corresponding value in column `B` is at least 500 should appear. I use the following formula:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$7;$B$2:$B$7>=500)
```

[image: Using Excel FILTER function as a source for dropdown]

Unfortunately, when I use the formula from cell `D2` as a source, I get an error message:

[image: The Source currently evaluates to an error.]

I have also tried to put the formula into a name and then reference the name as a source. But that gives me the same error.
The only workaround was to reference cell `D2` with a hash sign:

```
=D2#
```

[image: Reference spill range with hash tag in Excel]

However, I would prefer if I could use those dynamic array functions directly (either via name manager or in the validation interface). Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: It evaluates to an error because the cell does not meet the condition at this time. Some experimenting shows that you can use that dynamic array for list validation; but it won't appear as a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld. I am not sure if I understand you correctly. I have now tried to type the letter "E" to the cell that should contain the dropdown and then add the validation again (so the condition should be meet), but I get the same error message. So I am not quite sure if I understand what you mean with experimenting.

Comment: Hmmm. It seemed to work earlier as I described using numbers, but not with letters. I think you are going to have to stick with entering the formula in some cell, and using the Spill reference in your Data Validation List line as you have discovered.

Comment: I am afraid you are right. I was just hoping someone would know a workaround for this problem. Maybe, at some point Microsoft might fix that issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works to me.
Note that the reference M1 is the first value of the validation column. (I used M in my case)

```
=INDEX($B:$B;MATCH(M1;$A:$A;0))>=500
```