# Excel Data validation drop down list from a cell

Tags: excel, validation

I'm kind of stuck here.

In Excel with data validation, we can make a drop down list and go something like

[image: Data Validation Exmple]

But what if that "a, b, c, d" is populated inside a cell?

Is it possible to reference the list from that?

Say if I have a cell in `A2` contains a string list by using `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:D1)`, which will populate the "a,b,c,d" as desired for the list

What/How can I do to read A2 cell value into the Source Field of the Data validation?

**PS:** No, do not tell me I can just use `=A1:D1` in the Source field, as the actual cells I'm referencing are scattered throughout different sheets

Comment: Not tested but maybe with INDIRECT. Anyways, sounds kind of hard.

Comment: Perhaps you could gather a source list into a single, possible hidden, sheet? Rather than trying to solve a hard problem directly, replace it by an easier problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This possible, but a bit complicated. You will need to build an XML string from your value string and then filter its elements.

In my example, all the values that should appear in the dropdown are in cell A2, separated with `,`:

[image: Split string of values using FILTERXML in Excel]

We use the following formula to split the values:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2;",";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>";"//s")
```

**How it works**

First, we **build an XML string** using `SUBSTITUTE` (we substitute `,` with XML tags):

```
="<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2;",";"</s><s>")&"</s></t>"
```

This will result in the following:

```
<t><s>apples</s><s>pears</s><s>grapes</s><s>bananas</s></t>
```

Using `FILTERXML`, we can now **extract all values** between the `<s>` elements.

Be aware that `FILTERXML` will automatically spill over the necessary number of cells below `A5`, so be sure that there is enough space below A5.

Unfortunately, [you cannot directly use this formula in the validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62958449/12418842). But you can enter the formula in a hidden column or hidden sheet and then **use a spill reference**, like this one:

```
=A5#
```

[image: Spill reference dynamic array Excel]

**Result**

[image: Dropdown validation in Excel using spill reference]

Comment: Hi, but when I tried to copy your example with the syntax, they all returned errors (like: https://imgur.com/Lm4DF2Q). The one in A4 in that image above is replaced as =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s") instead, but it only returns one cell, but not a list of cells like yours. Although the function returns like what you showed (https://imgur.com/Uf1dBWQ), but it's only showing first cell. Which version of Excel are you using? I'm using Version 1908 Build 11929.20776

Comment: @Willy_Sunny Have you checked if you have to use `;`og `,` as an argument separator? In the first image, you use the semicolon, in the second you use comma. Am I correct that Excel 1908 is a "one-off" purchase and not an Office 365 subscription? It might be that `FILTERXML`only shows the first value in Excel 2019 (since dynamic arrays are not available). In this case, you can manually reference to (for example) the second element in the XML string, using xpath `"//s[2]"`. That way, you can manually drag the formula down. But that makes the solution more even complicated.